# Magento 2 - Obtain attribute values in PHTML template file

Tags: magento2, object-manager

Is there a proper method of getting an attributes list of values (drop-down list) within a PHTML template file that is being called from a CMS block?

I currently have a file mytemplate.phtml and I'm calling it within a CMS block using

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="mytemplate.phtml"}}
```

mytemplate.phtml has the following code

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    
function getExistingOptions( $object_Manager,$option) {

  $eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
  $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $option);
  $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

  $optionsExists = array();

  foreach($options as $option) {
      $optionsExists[] = ["value"=>$option['value'],"label"=>$option['label']];
  }
return $optionsExists;
}

$options=array();

$options['custom_option1']=getExistingOptions($obj,"custom_option1");
```

After reading other peoples comments on the matter, I appreciate that I may get flogged to death for using getObjectManager, so is there a better way of doing this? or calling the loaded Magento instance from within the template file? As I can't see how else I can obtain the attribute values to display on the page?

On another note, how do i find out the attributes default selected value as this isn't given when using `$attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();`?

Edit
I found how to get the default value `$attribute->getDefaultValue()`?